# RMI - Why there is a client.policy

Tags: java, rmi, policy

I search the web for awhile but did not find an answer to this questions. Why there is the need for a client.policy file?

Maybe someone could point me to the Oracle page with that topic. I found abondon sites only.

While the server needs to specify the access levels, why I have to put this file in my client too?

I would assume that the client tries to connect to the server and the server decides if that access is allowed or not. Putting the definion on the client side fells a little bit odd for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there is the need for a client.policy file?

The only time a client needs a .policy file is if it is running under a `SecurityManager,` and the only time it needs to do that in RMI is if you are using the RMI codebase feature to download class files to the client.

It has nothing to do with access control by the server.

Comment: All I want is to start a RMI server and allow local access to it. I read several answers telling me quite confusing stuff. Maybe due the fact that RMI in Java has changed. Right now I am using a SecurityManger on server and client site. Both using the same policy grant { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
}; I like to omit that on the client site if possible.

Comment: RMI has not changed in essentials since 1998. I repeat. If you're not using the codebase feature, and most people don't, you don't need a security manager or, therefore, a policy file either. At either end.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer I am looking for ;-)